# Unable to launch anaconda navigator in windows after tensor flow installation

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, anaconda

I tried to install tensor flow library in anaconda and after that I am unable to launch anaconda navigator. I am using windows machine and anaconda was working fine before. Error is as below:

An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up

```
Psutil.AccessDenied(pid=9636)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\india\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 620, in wrapper
return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\india\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 690, in cmdline
ret = cext.proc_cmdline(self.pid)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\india\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py", line 75, in exception_handler
return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\india\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 108, in start_app
if misc.load_pid() is None: # A stale lock might be around
File "C:\Users\india\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\misc.py", line 384, in load_pid
cmds = process.cmdline()
File "C:\Users\india\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 701, in cmdline
return self._proc.cmdline()
File "C:\Users\india\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 623, in wrapper
raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._name)
psutil.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=9636)
```

I have uninstalled and then installed anaconda, still facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it by simply resetting the navigator via Command Prompt:

```
C:\Anaconda3\anaconda-navigator --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the anaconda in win10 x64 (python3.x) and I got this problem this morning as well. All the things had been done in anaconda was that I installed a package called pywinauto, then I turned off the computer and went home.

I follow the suggestion from https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/4hBTDOcDzgo by lan, I update the anaconda by using the command.

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

However, the error occurred the same.

Then I reboot the computer and restart the anaconda, magic thing happens! the anaconda works fine!

I think maybe some configuration has been changed when I install the new package, and this change is conflicted with the current configuration which you need to reboot the computer to take effect. you should note that turn off computer then restart it is not equal to reboot it.

So, just reboot the computer and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by running in the anaconda prompt :

```
anaconda-navigator --reset
```